# IOS on touch and on release method

Tags: ios, view, timer, point

I'm workin' on new game in which i'm stuck at the moment. 
What i'm asking for is on touch view and on release view method. What i'm trying to do is, when you touch screen you get point where you touched it and timer starts, than when you released it you get another point where did you released it and timer stops. That i can get out some "speed" for rotation of button. 
Thanks for your time and answers.

Comment: I've tried to find on touch method on google but i didn't find any:(

Comment: Try reading Apple's documentation instead -- look at the "Responding to Touch Events" section of the UIResponder Class Reference and the "Event Handling Guide".

Comment: Thanks, now i found good tutorial about touches on youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-W4_oSWRvl8